# Sorting multiple sheets into 1 line and having each line display on a results page

Tags: excel

looking for some help speeding up sorting pages on a spreadsheet.

Currently we have 4 sheets absolutely packed with UK postcodes/zip codes.

At the moment we go into each sheet and sort the entire sheet to show the information for the specific postcode we enter. (Always returns one line of info each sheet)

Is it possible to just have a separate sheet where we enter the postcode it it finds the match from each sheet and displays 1 line from all 4 sheets? Hopefully that makes sense.

A idiot's guide tutorial would be great

Comment: Yes, use a vlookup. So, maybe cell B1 is the postal code you enter. Then Rows 2, 3, 4 and 5 would return your results. This works as long as the postal code on your sheets is to the left of what you want to return.

Comment: @Isolated i thought so, what would i need to type to include multiple sheets into 1 vlookup? the postcode is on the farthest left side of the sheet but i want it to display the information on the columns to the right of it on the results page

Comment: Give me a couple minutes and I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, let's say we have four sheets (sheet1, sheet2, sheet3 and sheet4). They all look like this:

[image]

Create your 5th sheet. Here, I'm calling it "lookup_here". You should look up how to use vlookup formulas as I'll fail to completely explain it here for lack of time. Basically, you are :

Looking up a value (such as 5F3322 postal code)  in a table array
(such as sheet1 columns A, B, C and D.... keeping in mind that your
lookup value must be in the first column of the array)

Then returning the column index (like column B is 2, column C is 3, etc).

And finally stating if you want an exact match (false) or approximate
match (true). Almost always use false.

Here is what the final output would look like, and I'll put some sample formulas below the picture.

[image]

So, you'll input your postal code value in cell B1. Then you will have formulas in B3 through D6. It will take some time to build these.

```
B3 Formula:   =VLOOKUP($B$1,Sheet1!$A:$D,2,FALSE)

B4 Formula:   =VLOOKUP($B$1,Sheet2!$A:$D,2,FALSE)

B5 Formula:   =VLOOKUP($B$1,Sheet3!$A:$D,2,FALSE)

B6 Formula:   =VLOOKUP($B$1,Sheet4!$A:$D,2,FALSE)
```

Column C formulas are similar, but the 2 before false will be a 3.
Column D formulas are similar, but the 2 before false will be a 4.